# Oracle function compiles successfully but throws error while executing PLS-00221: is not a procedure or is undefined

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sql-function

I have simple oracle function

```
create or replace function abs.test_func(test_in in number)
return number
is
   test_out number ;
BEGIN
test_out:=test_in;
RETURN test_out;
END;
```

if I compile it - it compiles successfully.
but when I run from PLSQL Developer SQL Window

```
 BEGIN abs.test_func(5); END;
```

it I gets the following errors

```
ORA-06550: line1, column8;
PLS-00221: 'TEST_FUNC' is not a procedure or is undefined
ORA-06550: line1, column8;
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

What's wrong with my function ?

Comment: How do you run the function?

Comment: It would help of you show the code that runs it Is the schema/user (abs) you create the function on the same user that you execute it on?

Comment: I call it from PLSQL Developer, updated my question.

Comment: A procedure and a function are two different things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `create function` code looks good, however you are not *invoking* the function properly. A function returns something, that you must either `select`, assign, print, or evaluate.

Here are a few examples of valid function calls:

```
-- print the return value
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(test_func(5));
end;
/

1 rows affected

dbms_output:
5


-- select the return value
select test_func(5) from dual;

| TEST_FUNC(5) |
| -----------: |
|            5 |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e83faa09f5278d2f2f484adbce447030)**

Comment: can you write simple example how can I call it from c# ?